# Java - implement equals on objects of different type

Tags: java, comparison, equals

Let's say I have an entity called Customer and a helper class called CustomerMapper which gets the values from the form. Then I'm sending this CustomerMapper to the service layer where I extract the values from the getters and add a new Customer into the database.

However now I need to iterate over a `List<Customer>` and check whether a customerID is contained in another `ArrayList<CustomerMapper>`. I read that the .contains() method calls .equals() on the element.. So i was wondering if it would be correct for me to implement equals() on Customer whereby I will be sending an object of type CustomeMapper and I will be comparing customer.getId() with customerMapper.customerId().

If the answer is no, please do elaborate why it is so.

EDIT:

This is what I've come up with. I've iterated through both arralists and created `Map<Long, Customer>` and `Map<Long, CustomerMapper>`. Basically I need to delete all Customer whose ids are not contained in the `Map<Long, CustomerMapper`>. now i iterate over `Map<Long, Customer>` and call `Map<Long, CustomerMapp>.contaisKey(currentElement).` Is this a good solution because this way I have three for loops.

Comment: I believe you can override the `equals()` method to return the values you want. Another, dirtier approach is to iterate through the list manually

Comment: I have the feeling that a List is not the best data structure for what you want to do. Have you thought of using a Map or a Set? (neither allow duplicates)

Answer (score 5):

It wouldn't make sense to do this by implementing an `equals()` method, simply because the two objects won't be equal.

Just extract the `id` and do a check if `CustomerMapper` has the same one.

Comment: The question is whether it is possible to compare objects of different types. Indeed, it is.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should only implement `equals` to return `true` for equal objects. Study the Javadoc on `equals`, especially what properties the relation imposed by it must possess, such as symmetry, transitivity and reflectivity. I think your intended implementation would fail on at least the first two, maybe also the last one. You'll just have to write an explicit loop that tests all members for your criterion.

#### Regarding your current solution:

Isn't it overkill to use maps? I propose simply collecting the `id`s from `CustomerMapper`s into a `HashSet` and using that set in the filtering loop on `Customer`s. BTW your idea to use `equals` **does not reduce the time complexity**; the loops would only be hidden behind the `contains` method call, resulting in total O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity. The solution with a Set/Map is in fact **less complex** due to O(1) hash lookup: the overall complexity is only O(n).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this. Think about any other use of collections, e.g. `java.util.Set`. You could run the following code:

```
Set<Object> customerLikeObjects = new HashSet<Object>();
customer.add(new CustomerMapper(13));

if (customer.contains(new Customer(13))) {
    // Run some code
}
```

The condition should check if a customer by ID 13 is already in the set and then run some code. But in fact, the Set doesn't contain the customer, but some "similar" object. As a matter of fact, you probably wouldn't even mix the two object types in a single set, would you?

While this "clever" solution seems to fix your problem, it would be very confusing, eventually. In fact, anything that is "clever" but just somehow doesn't feel right is always a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

As the "equals" method signature looks like `public boolean equals(Object that)` you can implement comparison between objects of any type. Probably you'll have to add something like

```
if (that instanceof CustomerMapper){
//do your comparison here
}
```

in your method implementation.

`instanceof` is rather a slow one, though.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it would be 'wrong' to override equals in that way is that it would break the [general contract of equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and could lead to weird, subtle (or weird, obvious) bugs

If you look at the [source of ArrayList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) contains() calls indexOf() which iterates over the list. So you're not taking a performance hit (and it it would arguably be more readable) to write a comparison method yourself.

Assuming both Customer and CustomerMapper have a `getId()` method

```
public Boolean containsCustomer(List<CustomerMapper> customerMappers, Customer customer) {
  if (customer == null  || customerMappers == null || customerMappers.size() == 0) {
    return false;
  } 
  for (int i = 0; i < customerMappers.size(); i++) {
    if (customer.getId().equals(customerMappers[i].getId())) {
     return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: the lists will, more often that not, have different sizes

Comment: Ah ha... what I'm imagining is you'd iterate over List<Customer> and for each customer call containsCustomer(someListOfCustomerMappers, theCurrentCustomer).